# Subtract 3 lists in a tuple from 1 tuple

Tags: python

What is the best way to do this? Looking to take the difference but not like this horrible way. For each A, B, C it is subtracted from `subtract from`

```
A = [500, 500, 500, 500, 5000]
B = [100, 100, 540, 550, 1200]
C = [540, 300, 300, 100, 10]
triples= [tuple(A),tuple(B), tuple(C)]
subtract_from = tuple([1234,4321,1234,4321,5555])
diff = []

for main in subtract_from:
   for i in range(len(triples)):
      for t in triples[i]:
          diff[i].append(main-t)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Instead of `for i in range(len(triples)): for t in triples[i]:`, you can just say `for t in triples`

Comment: Your last line caught `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @PrasadK but if you do `for t in triples`, it will have problem at the last line. Since `t` is a tuple and cannot do `main - t` operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
all_lists = [A, B, C]

[[i-j for i,j in zip(subtract_from,l)] for l in all_lists]

[
  [734, 3821, 734, 3821, 555],
  [1134, 4221, 694, 3771, 4355],
  [694, 4021, 934, 4221, 5545]
]
```

It is the best practice of doing this. no need to import any library, just use builtins.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using map and operator:

```
import operator

A = [500, 500, 500, 500, 5000]
B = [100, 100, 540, 550, 1200]
C = [540, 300, 300, 100, 10]

l = [A, B, C]

subtract_from = [1234,4321,1234,4321,5555]
diff = list((list(map(operator.sub, subtract_from , i)) for i in l))

print(diff)
# [[734, 3821, 734, 3821, 555], [1134, 4221, 694, 3771, 4355], [694, 4021, 934, 4221, 5545]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want tuples, use tuples explicitly without converting lists. That being said, you should write something like this:

```
a = 500, 500, 500, 500, 5000
b = 100, 100, 540, 550, 1200
c = 540, 300, 300, 100, 10

vectors = a, b, c

data = 1234, 4321, 1234, 4321, 5555

diff = [
    [de - ve for de, ve in zip(data, vec)]
        for vec in vectors
]
```

If you want list of tuples, use `tuple(de - ve for de, ve in zip(data, vec))` instead of `[de - ve for de, ve in zip(data, vec)]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think everyone else nails it with list comprehensions already so here's a few odd ones in cases if you are using a mutable lists and reusing it in an imperative style is acceptable style, then the following code can be done

```
A = [500, 500, 500, 500, 5000]
B = [100, 100, 540, 550, 1200]
C = [540, 300, 300, 100, 10]
subtract_from = (1234,4321,1234,4321,5555)

for i,x in enumerate(subtract_from):
    A[i], B[i], C[i] = x-A[i], x-B[i], x-C[i]

# also with map
#for i,x in enumerate(zip(subtract_from,A,B,C)):
#    A[i], B[i], C[i] = map(x[0].__sub__, x[1:])

diff = [A,B,C]
```

It's less elegant but more efficient*(...I have not done any benchmark for this claim)